# link button with form in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, forms

I build a login form and want when user click on submit button then other form show. I also add new form by file->add->new project
I use the name of 2nd form which is (welcom.vb) in the coding of submit.
the coding of submit button is

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As   EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
         welcom.show();
     End Sub
End Class
```

but compiler show error on welcom.show() line. It says you have to first declare the form welcom
and when i declare it as
dim welcom as new form
welcom.show()

then it shows only empty form
i want to link welcom form with submit button, how should i do this.

Thanks

Comment: remove ';' from welcom.show() and check spelling of that 2nd form name.

Comment: Dim wf as new welcom, then you can use wf.Show.

Answer (score 1):

He doesn't know the `welcome` form.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As   EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
         Dim welcom As New welcom
         welcom.show()
     End Sub
End Class
```